# Continued fraction expansion of Pi (oeis A001203).

Tags: number-theory, pi, continued-fractions

I would like to understand how you get the numbers
$$3+\frac{1}{7+\frac{1}{15+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{292+...}}}}$$
i.e. $\{3,7,15,1,292,...\}$ ([A001203](http://oeis.org/A001203)).

In the comments of [A046965](http://oeis.org/A046965) is explained a method for obtaining these numbers, or so it seems:

> To illustrate: [3] = 3/1 -> 3; [3,7] = 22/7 -> 22; [3,7,15] = 333/106;
>   106 is even -> [3,7,16] = 355/113 -> 355; [3,7,15,1] = 355/113 -> 355
>   (ignore); [3,7,15,1,292] = 103993/33102 -> [3,7,15,1,293] =
>   104348/33215 -> 104348

$7$ should be $= 2*3+1$, $15$ should be $= 2*7+1$ ... but 292?

Comment: It is a coincidence that for a while each partial quotient is one more than twice the preceding one. The partial quotients for $\pi$ have no known pattern, and none is expected.

Comment: Also related: [Continued fraction of a square root](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/265690/25554) explains how to calculate continued fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for any positive real number $x$ you get the continued fraction as follows.  Let $\lfloor x \rfloor = a_0$.  Then $x =  a_0 + \dfrac{1}{r_1}$ where $r_1 = \dfrac{1}{x - a_0}$.  Continue with $\lfloor r_1 \rfloor = a_1$, and $r_2 = \dfrac{1}{r - a_1}$, etc.  Then $$x = a_0 + \dfrac{1}{a_1 + \dfrac{1}{a_2 + \ldots}}$$ 
In this case $$\eqalign{x &= \pi\cr r_1 &= \dfrac{1}{\pi - 3}\cr
r_2 &= \dfrac{1}{r_1 - 7} = \dfrac{\pi - 3}{22 - 7 \pi}\cr
r_3 &= \dfrac{1}{r_2 - 15} = \dfrac{22 - 7 \pi}{106 \pi - 33}\cr
r_4 &= \dfrac{1}{r_3 - 1} = \dfrac{106 \pi - 33}{355 - 113 \pi}\cr}$$
and $292 = \lfloor r_4 \rfloor$.

Comment: If you are doing this for $\pi$ with a calculator, produce $\pi$ *in your calculator*. If you have a scientific calculator, use the $\pi$ key. The reason for this is that internally, the calculator keeps $1$ or $2$ *guard digits*. Informally, it knows $\pi$ to greater accuracy than it displays. Then subtract $\lfloor \pi\rfloor$ *in your calculator*, and invert with the $1/x$ key in your calculator, write down the greatest integer in the answer, subtract that in your calculator, and so on.

Comment: ... and the accuracy you need increases as this process goes on.